# Doing map and filter an array in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, filter

I have a list of object:

```
a = [{number:1},{category:[abc, cde]},{class:2}],
    [{number:2},{category:[abc, def]},{class:3}],
    [{number:3},{category:[def]},{class:4}]
```

below is my code:

```
            b
            .filter((a, index) => (a.category === 'def'))
            .map((a, index) => (
                  <div>{a.number}</div>
               )
            )
```

I need to list down object from 'a' which contain category = 'def'. Seems like I'm unable to filter it because my 'category' is in array format.
How do you guys fix it?

Comment: b is undefined?

Comment: object b is jz an example sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
b
.filter((v,i) => (v.category.includes('def')))
.map((v,i) => (
     <div>{v.number}</div>
))
```

Comment: I tried it but it still list down ALL the object in 'a'. What's wrong?

Comment: What do you want as your final output?

Comment: @Coolguy Can you post the full code? I'm so surprised it works if you try and key in to objects that don't have `category` and try to use `includes` on it

Answer (score 0):

Simply checks if def is in the array like:

```
a.category.includes('def')
```

Comment: i need to list down the object in 'a' which include category='def'. How to do it?

Comment: so you want all objects that have the category 'def' right?

Comment: yup, I just need to list down objects from 'a' which contain category 'def'

Comment: exactly, so replace `a.category === 'def'` with `a.category.includes('def')`. It checks if the `a.category` array contains the string `def``

Comment: I tried it but it still list down ALL the object in 'a'. What's wrong?

Comment: Edit your post and create a valid code snippet where you reproduce the error. Otherwise it's not possible to say

Answer (score 0):

Your objects are stored as an array of objects, which means you can't "key in" to check. So you have to check all of the elements of the array to see if 1. the key `category` exists and 2. see if `def` is in the object that contains `category`.

`Array#includes` has an older brother that is often overlooked. `Array#some`, which accepts a callback that will do what you need.

Then you have to use `Array#find` to traverse the filtered arrays again to find the object that has the key `number` and then print that value. You can also do this manually by using the index number of those objects, but it's far less robust.

```js
a = [[{number:1},{category:['abc', 'cde']},{class:2}],
    [{number:2},{category:['abc', 'def']},{class:3}],
    [{number:3},{category:['def']},{class:4}]]
    
h = a.filter((arr) => {
  return arr.some((obj) => {
    if (obj.category) {
      return obj.category.includes('def')
    } else {
      return false
    }
  })
})
console.log(h)
j = h.map((arr) => {
  let numObject = arr.find((obj) => ('number' in obj));
  if (numObject) {
    return numObject.number
  } else {
    return //something
  }
})
console.log(j)
```